# Passing array from PHP Function To Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, function

When calling a PHP function (which returns array) from Javascript I can't seem to view it.

The message I get is

> function Array() { [native code] }

How can I access items within the array.

When I use `alert(padd[0]);` the message returns undefined.

```
<?php

function getArray()
{
   $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
   return $cars;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function phpadd()
{
   var padd = <?php echo getArray();?>; 
   alert(padd);
}

</script>
```

Comment: can you use json ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `json_encode()` in the PHP function

```
<?php

function getArray()
{
    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    return json_encode($cars);
}
getArray();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function phpadd()
{
    var padd = <?php echo getArray();?>; 
    alert(padd);
}
phpadd();
</script>
```